# How to execute another powershell script with dynamic path, optional parameter and array parameter?

Tags: powershell

From a main PowerShell script I want to call another PowerShell script with an optional parameter and another non optional string array parameter. Something like this (with the dysfunctional call included for explanatory reasons):

```
$theOptionalParam = "maybe"
$theArrayParam = "A", "B"
$theDirectory = "SomeRelativePath"

#This is the part not working:
.\$theDirectory\SubScript.ps1 -OptionalParam $theOptionalParam -ArrayParam $theArrayParam
```

The SubScript.ps1 starts off like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$OptionalParam,
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$ArrayParam
)
```

But no matter what I try, I get an error or simply the first value of the array ("A") and the rest is discarded.

How do I execute the subscript correct with both the dynamic path, optional parameter and array parameter?

Comment: `& .\$theDirectory\SubScript.ps1 -OptionalParam $theOptionalParam -ArrayParam $theArrayParam`

Comment: @mhbuur Please post the exact error message in the question

Comment: It is working for me that way. If you have different behavior, then you should include command, that you actually trying, along with error message, you got.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Thanks alot - it was my ISE session that went sour. I restarted and now it works. Put that into an answer and I'll accept :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To interpret `.\$theDirectory\SubScript.ps1` as expandable string and expand value of `$theDirectory` variable, you should use invoke operator `&`.

```
& .\$theDirectory\SubScript.ps1 -OptionalParam $theOptionalParam -ArrayParam $theArrayParam
```

You can see that by looking at parsed AST:

```
{& .\$theDirectory\SubScript.ps1 -OptionalParam $theOptionalParam -ArrayParam $theArrayParam}.
Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements[0].GetType().Name
# ExpandableStringExpressionAst
{.\$theDirectory\SubScript.ps1 -OptionalParam $theOptionalParam -ArrayParam $theArrayParam}.
Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements[0].GetType().Name
# StringConstantExpressionAst
```

As you can see, if you does not use `&` invoke operator, then `.\$theDirectory\SubScript.ps1` interpreted as constant string, not as expandable string.