# Using variable in execution path

Tags: shell, powershell

I am trying to store a folder path as a variable in PowerShell, so that I can reuse that path for various task throughout my script:

```
# Local storage location    
$env:localTempFolder="TEMP"

# Download some executable and store it in the local temp folder
$env:downloadURL="http://somepage.com/foo.exe"
Invoke-WebRequest $env:downloadURL -OutFile $env:localTempFolder/foo.exe

# Execute the executable using the $localTempFolder variable
./$env:localTempFolder/foo.exe
```

The last statement gives the following error:

```
.\$env:localTempFolder\.exe : The term '.\$env:pci_TEMP\foo.exe' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
+ .\$env:pci_TEMP\foo.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\$env:localTempFolder\foo.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried adding various combinations of parentheses, quotes etc. to the last statement, but does not seem to get it right. What am I doing wrong, and where do I go from here?

Comment: `& ./$env:localTempFolder/foo.exe`

Comment: @PetSerAl, well, that was easy enough! Thank you! Could you perhaps post that as an answer?

Comment: I would say, that it is [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33415302), rather than posting same answer here. You need invoke operator to expand variables in command, else it will be interpreted as constant (not expandable) string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [PetSerAl pointed it out,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015584/using-variable-in-execution-path-in-powershell#comment67308495_40015584) you are *missing the call operator* `&`. I would also suggest you to use the `Join-Path` cmdlet to combine a path:

```
& (Join-Path $env:localTempFolder 'foo.exe')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, why should I use the Join-Path cmdlet over just simply concatenating them directly?

Comment: Its just a hint. In this example you might not use it but in general I use it so I don't have to worry about trailing slashes.

Comment: Okey, good to know! Thank you for the clarification.